# Discrete curve (re)-parameterization for curve resample

Tags: discrete-mathematics, curves

I'm working with cubic bezier curve fitting algorithms for a given discrete curve.

But I'm having some problems with the input data. The discrete curve representation used as input may vary, in a way that sometimes I recieve too many points in regions of high curvature, or a uniform distance between points, or either no pre-defined pattern.

Thus, I'm planning to use a good curve re-parameterization scheme so that the algorithm that I'm developing could run despite the nature of the curve, receiving always a discrete curve with a well-known pattern.

My question is: What is the possibilities for discrete curve (re)-parameterization for discrete curves that I should consider use in this task? My input is an ordered vector of points $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, representing the curve.

I have worked with chord-length parameterization, and it is a good option. But sometimes I have noticed that regions of high curvature lost some information (points discarded).

A interesting constraint for me is that I need one parameterization scheme that could preserve the original curve information as much as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no one scheme that is universally better than all others (as far as I know).

The chord-length scheme is the most commonly used.

Another common choice is the centripetal scheme, which is described [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html).

For a solution that is optimal in some sense, you should not pre-assign parameter values, you should treat them as unknowns that are to be computed as part of the interpolation process. This makes the problem **much** more complex, but it allows you to interpolate a larger number of data points. Specifically, you can interpolate 6 points with a cubic Bezier curves. For details, see [here](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~kozak/wikiang/index.php?title=Some_publications), and other papers by the same authors..